# ssrs iif expression return error instead of text, probably a format issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem with expression. If the `lotnumber` is not empty is works fine. Problem is if there is not `lotnumber` then expresion `return #error` instead of "no lot".

```
=iif(Fields!LotNumber.Value = "","no lot",(iif(left(Field!LotNumber.Value,1) = "M",right(Fields!LotNumber.Value,len(Fields!LotNumber.Value)-1),Fields!LotNumber.Value)))
```

Comment: can the lot number be null? or does it equal blank? Null does not equal blank and would need a different if statement. something like =iif(isNothing(Fields!LotNumber.Value)=True

Comment: it can be null. i don't get your expression what you mean by equal true?

Comment: its testing for null. Null does not equal "blank" so that if statement isn't accounting for nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still coming out with an error but i found the way around. Using replace

```
=iif(left(Fields!LotNumber.Value,1)= "M",replace(Fields!LotNumber.Value,"M",""),Fields!LotNumber.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your accounting for `null` values in the LotNumber field. Add `isNothing` to test for nulls. As of right now you are only testing for "Blank".

```
=iif(isNothing(Fields!LotNumber.Value)=True OR Fields!LotNumber.Value = "","no lot",(iif(left(Fields!LotNumber.Value,1) = "M",right(Fields!LotNumber.Value,len(Fields!LotNumber.Value)-1),Fields!LotNumber.Value)))
```